# MySQL get the matching rows for the min and max columns as in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, unpivot

Hellow experts ! I have a timesheets table as below

**timesheets table**

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|employee_no    |time             |device_id|
+-------------------------------------------+
|1              |2019-09-17 07:00 |001      |
|1              |2019-09-17 14:00 |002      |
|2              |2019-09-19 08:00 |002      |
|2              |2019-09-20 15:00 |003      |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I am using the following query to get the in and out times of the employees

```
select  timesheets.employee_no, 
        MIN(time) as in_time, 
        MAX(time) as out_time, 
        COUNT(`time`) as record_count
from timesheets 
where `time` between '2019-09-17 00:00:00' 
                      and '2019-09-17 23:59:59' 
group by timesheets.employee_no
```

and I get the desired output as expected as below

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|employee_no    |in_time          |out_time         |record_count|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|1              |2019-09-17 07:00 |2019-09-17 14:00 |2           |
|2              |2019-09-19 08:00 |2019-09-20 15:00 |2           |
+---------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Now i need to get the device_id's of the the in and out records as `time_in_device_id` and `time_out_device_id`. How to achieve that ?

Comment: The test for in and out seems a bit weak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `between` with times.  The following is simpler and more accurate.

MySQL does not offer "first()" and "last()" aggregation functions.  However, you can use string manipulation to do what you want:

```
select ts.employee_no, 
       MIN(time) as in_time, 
       MAX(time) as out_time, 
       COUNT(time) as record_count,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(device_id ORDER BY time), ',', 1) as first_device_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(device_id ORDER BY time DESC), ',', 1) as lasst_device_id
from timesheets ts
where `time` >= '2019-09-17' and
      `time` < '2019-09-18' 
group by ts.employee_no
```

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff your code works perfect. But could you kindly explain me as to why you say not to use between for dates ?

Comment: @Chamindar2002 . . . Because both end points are included in `BETWEEN`.  Your version is missing anything that happened between 23:59:59 and the next day.

Comment: Great use of ``SUBSTRING_INDEX()`` to avoid a subquery!

Answer (score 0):

use subquery

```
select a.*,b.deviceid as indeviceid,b1.deviceid as outdeviceid from
    (
    select  timesheets.employee_no, MIN(time) as in_time, MAX(time) as out_time, COUNT(`time`) as record_count
     from timesheets 
     where `time` between '2019-09-17 00:00:00' and '2019-09-17 23:59:59' group by timesheets.employee_no
    ) a join timesheets b on a.in_time=b.time
      join timesheets b1 a.out_time=b1.time
```